# Magento full page cache

Tags: php, magento

When full page cache is enabled(Enterprise), Up-sell products disappear from PDP after its reloading. Is it a bug(I found it on clear default magento store)? Any advices to solve this problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using the latest Magento and there is a block separated for upsell and the block is already hole-punched for you by the EE FPC module. As the hole-punch configured requires that the name of the block and the base block itself are correctly named as below,

```
<block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block>
<name>product.info.upsell</name>
```

It is necessary to create you own hole punch. Kindly follow these steps to proceed,

Insert the following into `etc/cache.xml`

```
catalog/product_list_upsell your.block.name CATALOG_PRODUCT_LIST_UPSELL
YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Container_ProductListUpsell 86400
```

Ensure that `<name>` and `<block>` accurately reflect the block class name/type for your upsell block.

Now, create a new model in `Model/Container/ProductListUpsell.`